# Converting 2s complement/ signed binary to int in R

Tags: r, binary, adc, 16-bit

I am receiving 16bit 2s complement or signed binary from an ADC IC. When I receive the data it looks like this

Timestamp , IP ,Frequency, Sensor, Data
132493498543616929, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -8739

132493498543626902, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -8739

132493498543636875, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -8739
132493498543636875, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -13108
132493498543656828, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -8739
132493498543666795, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -21846
132493498543676768, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -21846
132493498543676768, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -21846
132493498543686741, 10.0.0.236, 600.000, 321, -21846

I want to convert it to signed binary My minimum reproducible code is as follows

```
 library(binaryLogic)
 as.binary(-21846, signed=TRUE, logic=FALSE)
 [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

This gives me the binary value I want, however, when I use it as

```
Data_as_Binary <- as.binary(-21846, signed=TRUE, logic=FALSE)
Data_as_Binary
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE 
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

I have 16000+ values I need to convert in a dataframe and when I
use mutate or anything from tidyverse it gives back a list How do I collapse it into a single variable
converting it to hex is no problem but I have to have it in binary So now I have gotten it into binary but I need to add a 1 to the Least Significant bit how do I do that across a dataframe?
Thanks Amanda

Comment: The list is the only best way to store them. You could collapse them as a string, but that will require more computation to transform them back to binary

Comment: Do you know how to add a 1 in Binary to a Binary number? That is the last step that need to do and I am still not sure how to execute that

Comment: What do you mean by adding a 1 t a binary number?

Comment: I have to add a 1 to the LSB of this Binary number to take if from 2s complement/signed binary to the original data so the last step is adding a 1

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was able to come up with on my own and gives me what I want

```
 Data_as_bianary<- as.binary(RF_PWR_OFF_600$Data, signed = TRUE, size=2)
  

df<-as.data.frame(Data_as_bianary)
  
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(Data_as_bianary), ncol = 16))


df_2<-1*df

df_3<-(!df_2)*1

RF_PWR_OFF_600$DAta_to_bin  <- apply( df_3[ , 1:16 ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "" )


RF_PWR_OFF_600 <- RF_PWR_OFF_600%>%
  select(DAta_to_bin) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)
```